# Building Qt 4.8 on Windows 8 With VS2010 Pro

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, windows-8

I've installed VS2010 Pro on Windows 8 Consumer Preview (x64) for making **desktop** apps. (no Metro). I have downloaded the Qt 4.8 source and tried to configure it like this:

```
C:\Libraries\Qt4.8\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.0>configure -debug-and-relea
se -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-qt3su
pport
```

I get this error:

```
Qt: Untested Windows version 6.2 detected!
Unable to detect the platform from environment. Use -platform command lineargume
nt or set the QMAKESPEC environment variable and run configure again
See the README file for a list of supported operating systems and compilers.
```

What option/s do I need to set to make it compile?

EDIT: this works:

```
configure -debug-and-release -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-qt3support -platform win32-msvc2010
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `-platform win32-msvc2010` as an option to `configure`.

Comment: That appears to work but brings up an (unrelated?) error saying I need Perl to run syncqt

Comment: Yeah - that's necessary on older versions of windows too

Comment: @Tim : It appears that you are new to compiling open-source projects. Why are you building Qt from source anyway? You should just grab the precompiled Qt library for Windows 7 / Visual Studio and be done with it.

Comment: @EmileCormier because I did this before on XP with VS2010 and Qt 4.7 when you had to to get proper VS2010 support. Also because i want to get more experience :)

Comment: Qt 4.8 now has a binary package specifically for VS2010. I suppose compiling Qt from scratch is good practice for other libs where you don't have the luxury of pre-built binaries. :-)

Comment: @EmileCormier Last time I needed to get Qt, there were no 64-bit Vis.Studio binaries available from the downloads page, and the installer packages only had MinGW-built libraries.  Sometimes you just have to do it yourself to get what you want!